# Safari push notification in python using pyapns

Tags: django, python-2.7, safari, apple-push-notifications

**what is use of cert.pem and key.pem?
how can we create these file for safari push notification??** **OR** **can we send notification on safari desktop?**

```
import time

from apns import APNs, Frame, Payload

apns = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file='cert.pem',key_file='key.pem')
```

## Send a notification

```
token_hex = 'b5bb9d8014a0f9b1d61e21e796d78dccdf1352f23cd32812f4850b87'

payload = Payload(alert="Hello World!", sound="default", badge=1)

apns.gateway_server.send_notification(token_hex, payload)
```

Comment: Tudorizer bro please give me any suggestion.

Comment: what is cert.pem? http://serverfault.com/a/9717/216502

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.

```
payload = Payload(alert={
                "title": "",
                "body": "",
            }, sound="default", badge=1,url_arg={"name":"https://www.epush.in",},)
```